# Is this discontinuous function Riemann Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I have been asked to explain whether the following is Riemann integrable:

---

$$ f(x):=\begin{cases} 
      x & x< \frac{1}{4} \\
      \frac{1}{x} & x\geq \frac{1}{4} 
   \end{cases}
$$
Over the interval $[-1,1]$. I was thinking that I can say this function is bound between $0$ & $4$, and I know that all bounded functions are Riemann Integrable. However, I wasn't sure if this would be a sufficient explanation (If I am even correct).

Comment: Not all bounded functions are Riemann Integrable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try writing 
$$
\int_{-1}^1f(x)\;\mathrm dx=\int_{-1}^{1/4}x\;\mathrm dx+\int_{1/4}^1\frac{1}{x}\;\mathrm dx
$$
Both pieces we know are integrable, indeed they are bounded and continuous.

It would probably be good to note that the integral doesn't care about discontinuities at a (or countably many) point(s).

Edit: A little more justification for why we don't need to care about the contribution at $\frac{1}{4}$, note that 
$$
\left|\int_{1/4-\epsilon/8}^{1/4+\epsilon/8}f(x)\;\mathrm dx\right |\leq\epsilon/4\sup_{-1\leq x\leq 1}|f(x)|=\epsilon\to 0
$$
as we shrink $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 4):

The function $f$ is Riemann-integrable, but your justification doesn't work. It is *not* true that every bounded function is Riemann-integrable; take $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$, for instance.

The function $f$ is Riemann-integrable because it is bounded and it is discontinuous only at a single point (which is $\frac14$).

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, am I correct in saying however, that all unbounded functions are not Riemann Integrable?

Comment: Since this is an elementary question, it might be worth explicitly noting that $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}$ is just the function which returns $1$ for rationals (between 0 and 1) and $0$ for irrationals.

Comment: @George Yes, you are correct. *By definition*, every Riemann-integrable function is bounded.

Comment: Yes, it is part of the standard definition. The upper and lower sums don't make sense if $f$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can note down the following two theorems which don't require measure theory for their proof.

> **Theorem 1**: If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.
>
> **Theorem 2**: If $f$ is monotone on $[a, b] $ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.

The first theorem can be generalized further (again without recourse to measure theory) to the following:

> **Theorem 3**: If $f$ is bounded on $[a, b] $ and the set $D$ of discontinuities of $f$ on $[a, b] $ has only a finite number of limit points then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.

An immediate consequence of the above theorem is that *$f$ is Riemann integrable integrable if $f$ is bounded and the set $D$ of its discontinuities is finite*. And that's what we need here. The given function is bounded and discontinuous at just a single point and therefore Riemann integrable.

Comment: Is saying, "... the set $D$ of discontinuities of $f$ on $[a,b]$ has only a finite number of limit points" equivalent to saying $D$ doesn't contain intervals but only a countable (finite or infinite) points?

Comment: @William: $D$ can't contain an interval because then there would be an infinite number of limit points. And yes $D$ will also be countable, but that needs a bit more effort to prove. Essentially you can reduce the problem to $D$ having a single limit point $c$ and $D\setminus \{c\} =D\setminus\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(c-1/n,c+1/n)=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (D\setminus (c-1/n,c+1/n))$.

Comment: @William: but you can see that these are not equivalent as $D$ may be set of rationals in $[0,1]$ so that it is countable but every point of interval $[0,1]$ is a limit point of $D$ so that it has infinite number of limit points.