# Riemann integrable function which is discontinuous at an uncountable number of points on every open set?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $n$ be some positive integer. Does there exist a Riemann integrable function
> $$f: [0,1]^n \to \mathbb{R} $$
> with the following property: for every non-empty open subset of $U \subset (0,1)^n$, the set
> $$ \{x \in U \ \mid \ f \text{ is discontinuous at } x \} $$
> is uncountable?

I don't really know how to approach this. I know that a function is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

I tried to see if, for instance, I can somehow construct a function like this, such as the characteristic function on the Cantor set in $[0,1]$ (which does not satisfy the above property) and extend it to $[0,1]^n$, but I did not succeed.

Comment: If you want a Riemann integrable function then it can admits only a finite number of "jump" discontinuities

Comment: The set of jump discontinuous can be countable, not just finite, right?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601120/is-this-discontinuous-function-riemann-integrable

Comment: What you sent me is not an "if and only if statement"

Comment: For an example of function that has an infinite countable points of discontinuity but it is not R. integrable take the Dirichlet function defined $1$ on the rationals between $0$ and $1$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: Take, for instance, the set $[0,1]$, and write it as $$[0,1] = [1/2, 1] \cup  \bigcup_{n=2}^\infty \left[ \frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n} \right), $$ and then take a function $f$ that is constant on all these subintervals and set $f(0) = 0$ (and also assume that this $f$ is bounded). This function is Riemann integrable, and has a countably infinite number of jump discontinuities.

Comment: Also, the Dirichlet function is discontinuous in every point. For if you fix $x \in [0,1]$, then if you approach $x$ via the rationals, then the limit of the Dirichlet function is $1$, but if you approach $x$ via the irrationals, the limit is $0$.

Comment: Dirichlet function is everywhere discontinuous by just choosing any $\epsilon<1$ on the definition. @S.T. Do you know if the result you posted holds if we just ask $\{x\in[0,1] : f \text{ is discontinuous at } x\}$ to be uncountable?

Comment: It should be well known that monotone functions have jump discontinuities only, there are at most a countable number of them and it is Riemann integrable. This is for single variable calculus. Also as noted Dirichlet function is discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: @R.V.N. The characteristic function on the Cantor set is discontinuous on the Cantor set, which is uncountable, but it is still Riemann integrable, as the Cantor set has measure zero.

Comment: Between every pair of distinct rationals, construct a Cantor set. Then use the result mentioned in the first comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function). (I do not know if there is something more elementary.)

Comment: How do you define such a set if between any pair of rationals there are other infinite rational numbers?

Comment: @David Mitra: See the integrability criteria [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/870108/13130), let $\{I_n: \; n = 1,\;2,\;\ldots \}$ be the rational-endpoint open subintervals of $[0,1],$ let $C_n$ be a Cantor set (or any closed set) of Hausdorff dimension greater than $1-\frac{1}{n}$ contained in $I_n,$ and use the construction in Proof Sketch [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/933781/13130) (note comment regarding "pairwise disjoint"). This gives a Riemann integrable function whose discontinuities in every open interval has Hausdorff dimension $1$ (MUCH stronger than uncountable).

Comment: @DavidMitra This is an interesting construction, and I think it's correct. Could you please write it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example for $n=1$:

It is known that if $S$ is a  $F_\sigma$ set (a countable union of closed sets) in $\Bbb R$, then there is a function $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow\Bbb R$ whose set of discontinuities is $S$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function) for a reference to a proof.

So, it suffices to find an $F_\sigma$ in $\Bbb R$ of measure zero with the property that its intersection with any non-degenerate open interval is uncountable.  Towards this end, for each pair of distinct rationals, construct a Cantor set between them; then take the (countable) union over all such sets. It is easily verified that this gives what's required.

Also, see Dave Renfro's comments above.

Comment: To follow-up on my yesterday's comment (I was out of characters, the comment having 2 or 3 characters left, and didn't feel like continuing with another comment), the reason we get "everywhere of Hausdorff dimension $1$" is that given any nonempty open interval $I,$ there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $I_n\subseteq I,$ and so for every $\epsilon > 0$  and for every nonempty open interval, the intersection of the set with that open interval has Hausdorff dimension greater than $1-\epsilon,$ which implies the intersection of the set with that open interval has Hausdorff dimension $1.$